# How to use some APIs from Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a web app (c# .net server-side language) and I need to call some APIs, as below:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{user-id}/presence
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id-for-teams}/members
```

I don't know much about it, so I have many doubts.
What's the best way to get a token (never expire) without a user's interaction screen for loggin or is not possible? If anyone has ideas/tips for it, I thank you so much.

Best regards!

Comment: I don't think you can use the /presence endpoint because it doesn't support app context. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma, thank you for your comment, my application is an webapp (ASP.net MVC / C#), Do you know how can I use this API (presence)?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you use the daemon-based [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) when there is no user login. This flow will return an access token by default (not a refresh token), and the [lifetime of the access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes) is about 1 hour , So if you want to obtain an access token that never expires, you need to use powershell to [create a token lifetime policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/configure-token-lifetimes), and then assign the policy to the service principal to set the token lifetime.

By the way, for the first api, you cannot use the `/presence` endpoint because it does not support application context. For the second api, you should change `/me` to `/users/{user id}`.

Comment: Carl, thanks, In fact, what I really need is to use these APIs, so there is no problem if the user needs to log into the Microsoft account, we can change this requirement, with that, what is the best form of login that you recommend to use these APIs?

Answer (score 0):

You can check users presence using this C# code piece:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var presence = await graphClient.Me.Presence
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

and calling the api from the controller class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll check it, but it's possible to use presence API with an Asp.net MVC application?

Comment: Yes it is possible but you should have a valid Graph API token.